Why were cross cousin marriage happening when it is banned in scriptures?
There were some cross cousin marriages happening in Mahabharat, not only Subhadra-Arjuna, but few others also.
I am asking , how it was happening when it is banned in multiple scriptures like Manusmriti, and few others I think Gautam Sutras or something like that.

To begin with, concept of cross-cousin or parallel-cousin does not exist is shastras.
Marriages are based on the concept of sagotra and sapinDa.
Vedas and smriti do prohibit sapinDa marriages upto certain degrees :

shatapATa brAhmaNa 1.8.3.6 :
tadvā etat | samāna eva karmanvyākriyate tasmādu samānādeva
puruṣādattā cādyaśca jāyate idaṃ hi caturthe puruṣe tṛtīye
saṃgacāmaha iti videvaṃ dīvyamānā jātyā āsata etasmādu tat
Thus the separation (of the eater and the eaten) is effected in one and the same act; and hence from one and the same man spring both
the enjoyer (the husband), and the one to be enjoyed (the wife): for
now kinsfolk (gatyah) live sporting and rejoicing together, saying,
“In the fourth man (or) third (i.e. generation) we unite.” And
this is so in accordance with that (separation of the spoons).
gobhila grhya sutra III, 4, 3-5
'One must take for one's wife one who is not of the same gotra, or one
who is not sapinda to one's mother,'
BAUDHÂYANA PRASNA I, ADHYÂYA 1, KANDIKÂ 2 :

We will explain those (peculiar) to the south.

They are, to eat in the company of an uninitiated person, to eat in the company of one's wife, to eat stale food, to marry the daughter of
a maternal uncle or of a paternal aunt.


brahmavaivartapurANa kruSNajanmakhanDa ch 115 :
krshna had given away his sister subhadra to arjuna, the marriage with
the daughter of maternal uncle is not prohibited in the south.

harisvami bhashya on shatapATa brahmaNa 1.8.3.6 addresses all the above points and maps it to sapinDa marriage prohibition listed in smriti and calls it as Srauta vivaha.
However harisvami bhashya also mentions a rig veda sukta verse which allows sapinDa marriage and calls it as rig vivaha


In short, two types of marriages Srauta vivaha (sapinDa restriction rules) & rig vivaha (without sapinDa restriction rules)
Above rig verse is found in rig veda khila sukta 2,14.6 whose translation is below :

sagotra (same gotra/pravara) marriage restriction, however, doesn't seem to have any exceptions and applies in both cases.
Thus marriages of arjuna-subhadra, pradyumna-rukmAvatI, aniruddha-rochanA & krShna-nIlA would be rig vivaha.
